# How to set object property values from sub object in asp.net core API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can I set the `internal` property `user_id` value from sub object `User.user_id`. I checked with breakpoint and it's always null while `user.user_id` has value as sent in request body

**Class**

```
public class Project
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}

    // user_id is null while user.user_id has value as sent in request body
    internal int? user_id {get; set;}

    public User user {get; set;}

    public Project()
    {
        user_id = user?.user_id;
    }
}

public class User
{
    public int user_id {get; set;}
    public int user_name {get; set;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Project project)
{
    return Ok(project);
}
```

Comment: Constructor will be called only when you create a new instance for Project.

Comment: Then how do I map? Should I make a static function `map()` and call it on controller all the time?

Comment: Hi @VikashRathee,check my answer below.

Comment: @VikashRathee So you are using the internal property `user_id` only to read the `user_id` of the `user` object, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your model like below:

```
public class Project
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    internal int? user_id { get; set; }
    private User _user;
    public User user
    {
        get { return _user; }
        set
        {
            _user = value;

            // Assign user_id 
            user_id = value.user_id;
        }
    }
    //public User user { get; set; }

}
```

Result:

[image]

For update:

You could also change your property like below:

```
internal int? user_id { get { return user.user_id; } }
public User user { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the internal property `user_id` solely to read the value of `user_id` property from the `user` object. If that is the case, then you could just do **exactly** that - read the `user_id` of `user` object through it, like -

```
public class Project
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    internal int? user_id { get { return user.user_id; } }

    public User user { get; set; }
}
```